# Churn predictor for customer purchases

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm working on a little project to do with predicting if a customer could be labelled as no longer buying from a company after a certain time. I have a `df`:

```
ID         purchase      end_of_purchase
ab1       2017-01-01       2017-01-07
cd2       2017-01-03       2017-02-06
ab1       2017-02-08       2017-02-09
ef3       2017-02-09       2017-02-12
ab1       2017-05-01       2017-05-22
```

What I want is, when a customer buys a product, the clock starts. If in 1 months time their current purchase hasn't expired or they've bought a new product they can be considered 'alive' or `0`. However, if their product has expired and they haven't made a new purchase within 1 month of their original, they can be considered dead or `1`. These values would appear in the column `dead_alive`. This then needs to be checked as if a customer is labelled dead but they have returned to purchase again this method would be inaccurate. My desired output is `df_final`:

```
ID         purchase      end_of_purchase    dead_alive      actual
ab1       2017-01-01       2017-01-07           0              0
cd2       2017-01-03       2017-02-06           1              1
ab1       2017-02-01       2017-02-09           1              0
ef3       2017-02-09       2017-02-12           1              1
ab1       2017-05-01       2017-05-22           1              1
```

As you can see ID `ab1` is assigned `0` on the first row as their subsequent purchase is equal to or less than 1 month later. Their second purchase however is labelled `1` as their next purchase is almost 3 months later.

One thing I'm largely struggling with is customers such as `cd2` and `ef3` as they only make 1 purchase and I have no way of judging whether they return on any future purchase but they still have a purchase expiry date that can be over 1 month. In addition, all customers on their final purchase should have an `actual` value of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to have one more dataframe
Say initial_df

```
ID         purchase      
ab1       2017-01-01       
cd2       2017-01-03       
ab1       2017-02-01       
ef3       2017-02-09       
ab1       2017-05-01
```

and build final df from initial_df

```
ID        dead_alive      actual
ab1       1               1
cd2       1               1
ab1       1               0
ef3       1               1
```

Use pandas group by on ID after sort the date. Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah building this all in one dataframe does seem like it would be quite difficult